# .unique() is not returning a full array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, unique

```py
df.loc[df['salary'] == '>50K', 'education'].unique()

Returns: array([], dtype=object)
```

I am a bit confused as to why my array is returning empty? It's supposed to be full of the assortment of "education" values corresponding to earning more than 50K. Here's a [link](https://www.kaggle.com/kashnitsky/a1-demo-pandas-and-uci-adult-dataset-solution) to where you can see the dataset and tentative solutions, just wondering why my code is returning blank! Thanks!!

Comment: Does `df.loc[df['salary'] == '>50K', 'education'].head()` return the expected value?

Comment: Hey thanks I figured it out, totally unrelated to the syntax of the code but there was a space before the >50K, so rather than == '>50K' which returned nothing because no object was equal to that, I needed to do == ' >50K' which returned the full array! thanks for your help I really appreciate it